# 文法について "とを" はどういう意味ですか?

Tags: grammar

> Mekong Rest Stopはハイグレードなサービスエリアで、自然や『緑―清潔―美』と言った自然の特徴**とを**建築に取り入れるように設計され、旅行者が移動する際、休憩したりリラックスしたり、飲食したりします。

上記の"特徴とを建築に取り入れるように" には 分からないことがあります。
"とを" はどういう意味ですか?

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「とを」は「を」のタイポではないでしょうか？前者は文法的な正確さを抜きにすれば、意味が分かる気がしますが（それ以外は問題ないので）、後者の方が文章全体を自然な印象にします。

Comment: たぶん「自然と〜の特徴とを」か「自然や〜の特徴などを」かのどちらかを書きたかったのに筆が滑って呼応をミスったんじゃないかと思います。気持ちは分からなくもないです。

Comment: ちょっと検索すると、[「～と～を」と「～と～とを」と(?)の使い分け？](https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/321533.html)という回答がありました。『歴史的には、二つのものを並列する場合には、奈良時代以降ずっと、「Ａ**と**Ｂ**とを**まぜる。」のように、「と」をいちいち下につけるのが原則だったようです。』と解説されてあり、@brocolliさんが「自然と〜の特徴とを」と書きたかったのではないかと言う考えが、私の『「とを」は「を」のタイポではないか』と言う考えよりは正しそうですね。

Comment: @kimiTanaka さんの手前恐縮ですが、よく読むと「自然と『』～の特徴と」が並列と考えると意味がよく取れないので、やっぱりどこかおかしい感じがしますね…

Comment: @broccolifacemask-cloth さんが仰るように筆が滑って呼応やら何やらがごっちゃになったんでしょうね。元の文章は観光地のレビューと思われるので、他の旅行者に対して、どういった場所か最低限雰囲気が伝われば良いのかなという程度で書いたのかなと。

Comment: @kimiTanaka あ、もしかして出典発見しました？この文章を読む限りだと、文の流れが変なところもあるので、機械翻訳か質の悪い翻訳の可能性もあるかなとか考えてました

Comment: kimi Tanakaさん、 broccoli facemask - clothさん。本当にありがとうございます。    
2人の答えのどちらでも正しいと思います。  「とを」は「を」のタイポかもしれません。  しかし、タイポじゃなかったら,　roccoli facemask - clothさんの答えも正しいだと思います。  たぶん、文章の筆者は「「自然と〜の特徴とを」か「自然や〜の特徴などを」と書きたかったと思います。  下記の文章はインターネットで見つけました。「~ と ~ とを」を使っています。  「フランス18世紀後半の「理性の時代の建築」の流れを汲む革新の精神**と**幻想性**とを**建築に求めた「革命期の建築家」の一人として知られる。」   Link:https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/268216344.pdf